# Replace the value in arrray by another aarray

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a mask array: `[0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0]`. 
And a values array: `[3,4,5,6,7]` 
Which is the best way that I can replace all value 1 in mask array into the values array?
Expected result: `[0,0,0,0,3,4,0,0,5,6,0,7,0]`
I am working with large array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy), and a values length equal to the number of 1s.

Use boolean indexing:

```
mask = np.array([0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0])
values = [3,4,5,6,7]

mask[mask==1] = values
```

If `values` can be longer than the sum of 1s:

```
m = mask==1
mask[m] = values[:m.sum()]
```

Output:

```
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 5, 6, 0, 7, 0])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use iterator:

```py
mask = [0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0]
nums = iter([3,4,5,6,7])

output = [next(nums) if m else 0 for m in mask]

print(output) # [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 5, 6, 0, 7, 0]
```